# UBUNTU 18 install on ASUS Prime H510M-E 1200 motherbord

Tags: boot, grub2, asus

My new HW is : ASUS motherboard Prime H510M-E with Intel I5 10400 2.9 GH 12M 1200 Tray / 8 GB memory + 448 GB SanDisk SSD

I have a UBUNTU 18.04 64 bit bootable stick (USB). This stick boots to Grub and shows some options (`- start Ubuntu from stick`   OR `- Install Ubuntu`) but when one of these options is selected the screen shows "couldn't..."  for a very short time  and does not boot.

Any idea? The stick worked in the past on an Intel I5 NUC.

More: When slecting <kbd>F2</kbd> and BIOS goes up is says (<kbd>F8</kbd> pressed) “no bootable device”. I tried to change the BIOS (via <kbd>F7</kbd>)  to: disable fast boot, AiTweaker/ Asus performance disabled. Secure boot mode = custom (or standard), OS type = "Other OS". These all did not help. The HW does work with WIN 10/11 though.

Any idea how to solve for installing UBUNTU and what BIOS changes are needed if possible at all?

Comment: Didn't the H510 platform come out after 18.04 was released?  You may need to install a newer version of Ubuntu that supports that hardware. Also, you should make sure that your BIOS is up-to-date.  You will need to consult the motherboard manufacturer's documentation for the specific model that you have. When updating BIOS it's essential that you follow their directions exactly to prevent bricking your hardware. We don't provide instructions on how to update BIOS here because every board is different and it can be catastrophic if you mess up. Defer to the manufacturer's instructions.

Comment: FYI:  Your title says Ubuntu 18 which to me implies Ubuntu Core 18, ie. a *year* or *headless* server product as no desktop is released for *year* product, but then you mention a different 18.04 product in your question (18.04 Server or 18.04 Desktop isn't specified).  18 != 18.04; Ubuntu has had *year* or *snap* only products since 2016.  Please be precise with details.

Comment: Have; you updated UEFI from Asus and firmware on SSD. And newer distribution probably is required. You do need to have UEFI installer and boot in UEFI boot mode. What video card do you have or just Intel chip's video?

Comment: - I meant USB debuntu 18.04 desktop . will try Ubuntu 20
- The BIOS is pretty new ( Oct 2021)
- The USB device has EFI directory with boot dir and grub under
- Is there free access  to ASUS documentation and release notes ?
- I have Intel's chip on board . no add on  video card